# (workaround solution in last comment) output to latex of string from R sections in knitr with backslash characters

Tags: regex, r, latex, knitr

I want to use the latex `\underbrace` command within a R section of a knitr document.
The goal is to replace all the occurrences of a given word in a text by the same word, with underbrace and some other string, say its translation in some other language (the one that's named "after" in the code below), and have all this appear in a latex->pdf

This is my example code (I also tried with `paste` and `cat` instead of `paste0`)

```
<<echo=FALSE,results='asis'>>=

require(tm)
require(stringr)
require(textcat)
require(xtable)
require(koRpus)
require(dplyr)

my.text.before <- "the sea is blue."
string.before <- "blue"
string.underneath <- "colour"

string.after <- paste("$\\underbrace{",string.before,"}_\\textrm{",string.underneath,"}$",collapse="",sep="")
my.text.after <- str_replace_all(my.text.before,string.before,string.after) 
print(my.text.after)
@
```

but I can't get it to generate eventually

`\underbrace` in my latex file. Depending on all the tweaks I tried (such as `\\\\underbrace`), I obtain either underbrace or `\\underbrace` in my .tex file, but never what's needs.

I managed to do this sort of operation with `\textbf` instead of `\underbrace`, but `\textbf` doesn't require to be in latex math mode, maybe that's the point (maybe not). I tried `\$` instead of `$` but it doesn't help.

Comment: It's unclear what you're doing with `my.text.after` to include it in the document. Please try to create a complete, minimal reproducible example that we can run and get the same results as you.

Comment: edited in this direction, thx.

Comment: try `str_replace_all(my.text.before,fixed(string.before),string.after)`

Comment: I ended up with a satisfactory workaround, as follows :
    `\renewcommand{\textunderscore}[2]{$\underbrace{\textrm{#1}}_\textrm{#2}$}`
to avoid the `$` (latex math) and the `\u` starting the `\underbrace`, which won't execute correctly.

followed by :

 `paste("\textunderscore{",string.before,"}{",string.underneath,"}",collapse="",sep="")`